# Hybrid Honda Fit 2014

Tags: electrical

I just did a transmission exchange, now the car starts for about 10 seconds then it shuts down, then the battery light comes on. What is causing this ?

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question? The battery light is likely coming on because the engine shut down/ alternator is no longer spinning. Are there any other lights on the dash like a key/ security light? Any engine codes? Is this an automatic transmission?

Comment: it's a dual wet clutch automatic transmission.  There were no security light or engine code on the dash.

Answer (score 0):

If there's enough power to start the car (ruling out battery/ charging system), no lights on the dash, no codes, and the engine idles strong for the same amount of time (ruling out mechanical issues and key issues) before shutting off, you may have a module malfunctioning or without power. There are several instances of Hondas with a blown MICU (body control/ multiplexer) fuse that idle and then die. CAN bus might also be an issue, but usually that causes all sorts of dash lights.

I would check all fuses, and if everything looks fine use a (dealership level) scan tool that can query different body modules for faults.

Comment: We scanned the hybrid system and it showed the code, POAE1:03. Then it showed 18 possible causes. Do you have any suggestions or we just have to work through all 18 until we find the cause?

Comment: Start with the cheapest solutions first :)
It sounds like it might be a fault with the HV relays? I would start with those since they're easy to diagnose, but people online have had issues all the way down to the fuse in the battery pack. It's odd that you don't have any lights on the dash - I would think you would have an IMA light with that code

Comment: we find the problem,  it's the hybrid battery,  I should have mentioned this earlier. the car was out for over a year, as we had difficulty sourcing the transmission. So the hybrid battery needs to be charged, its weak. How can that be done.

Comment: where can I find the HV relays on this car?